# How to fix this error on installing Eel using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, eel

I receive the following output when I give `pip install eel`

```
C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\TriacleGST.py>pip install eel
Collecting eel
  Using cached Eel-0.14.0.tar.gz (17 kB)
Collecting bottle
  Using cached bottle-0.12.19-py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting bottle-websocket
  Using cached bottle-websocket-0.2.9.tar.gz (2.0 kB)
Collecting future
  Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting gevent-websocket
  Using cached gevent_websocket-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting gevent
  Using cached gevent-20.9.0.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packag
es\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qz6db80l\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --
no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5' 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_
implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (33 lines):
  Collecting cffi>=1.12.3
    Using cached cffi-1.14.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (179 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=3.0a5
    Using cached Cython-3.0a6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
  Collecting greenlet>=0.4.17
    Using cached greenlet-0.4.17.tar.gz (61 kB)
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached setuptools-51.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.36.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
  Collecting pycparser
    Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for greenlet, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: pycparser, wheel, setuptools, greenlet, Cython, cffi
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: started
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Us
ers\\Moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k1pglky8\\greenlet_ceacfe35e8874af3a14fc0d3401490d0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Moham\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k1pglky8\\greenlet_ceacfe35e8874af3a14fc0d3401490d0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__)
;code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Moham\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-record-6gy4x5s9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qz
6db80l\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qz6db80l\overlay\Include\greenlet'
           cwd: C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k1pglky8\greenlet_ceacfe35e8874af3a14fc0d3401490d0\
      Complete output (11 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG
 /MD -Ic:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:
\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt /Tcgreenlet.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\greenlet.obj
      greenlet.c
      c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(201): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No suc
h file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' fa
iled with exit code 2
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, to
kenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k1pglky8\\greenlet_ceacfe35e8874af3a14fc0d3401490d0\\setup.py'"'"'; __
file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Moham\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k1pglky8\\greenlet_ceacfe35e8874af3a14fc0d3401490d0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize
, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' instal
l --record 'C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6gy4x5s9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Moham\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qz6db80l\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qz6db80l\overlay\Includ
e\greenlet' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\moham\appdata\local\progr
ams\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Moham\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qz6db80l\ov
erlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 40.8.0' wheel 'Cython >= 3.0a5'
 'cffi >= 1.12.3 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'greenlet >= 0.4.17 ; platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' Ch
eck the logs for full command output.
```

Any idea whats the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe better to open issue at https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel/issues

Comment: @OneCricketeer that's not the issue. It happens with other pip installs also